# Does $P(EF) = P(E) \cdot P(F)$?

Tags: probability

Question in the title. It seems like a silly question, but I literally cannot find an answer to this anywhere.

Comment: Yes, if $E$ and $F$ are independent events.

Comment: What do you mean by $P(EF)$? Do you mean the probability of both $E$ and $F$, i.e. $P(E \cap F)$?

Comment: Fly by Night, I believe so.  I'm learning Bayes' Theorem in a Data Mining class but haven't taken probability yet.  I know that $P(E|F) = P(EF)/P(F)$ but I want to make sure that $P(EF) = P(E) \cdot P(F)$

Answer (score 3):

In general the answer in no. Besides, this is exactly the definition of independence of events: two sets $A,~B$ in a (probablity) space $\Omega$, equipped with a probalbility measure, are called independent if $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B)$. And in general, two events $A,~B$ are not independent.
For an easy example, take an event $A$ whose probability $p$ satisfies $0<p=P(A)<1$. Take $B=A$ (so $A,~B$ are not independent) and $p=P(A)=P(A\cap B)\neq P(A)P(B)=p^2$.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathsf P(E~F)=\mathsf P(E)\cdot\mathsf P(F)$ *only* for independent events; otherwise there would be *no point* to Bayes' Theorem.

Conditional Probability exists as a distinct concept because not all events are independent.

$$\mathsf P(E\mid F) ~=~ \frac{\mathsf P(E~F)}{\mathsf P(F)}\quad\mathop{\Large =}\limits^{\textsf{iff independent}}\quad \frac{\mathsf P(E)\cdot\mathsf P(F)}{\mathsf P(F)}~=~\mathsf P(E)$$

Instead, Bayes' Theorem is derived by: $$\mathsf P(E\mid F) ~=~ \frac{\mathsf P(E~F)}{\mathsf P(F)}~=~ \frac{\mathsf P(E)\cdot\mathsf P(F\mid E)}{\mathsf P(F)}$$